# Are math-based economics questions welcome here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I asked a question on the economics stack about a dynamic, structural model. It's a self study question. The difficulty I'm having with it stems from me not knowing how to set up the problem mathematically and actually solve it. (It's [this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/21604/1506)). Are questions like this welcome on the math site? I strongly suspect not but I thought I would make sure.

(I have a vested interest in this of course because the question would get much more visibility on the math site!)

Comment: I think your question would be very welcome (on MSE that is, not meta-MSE). Go for it!